# How show a function in inputs of another function?

Tags: functions, notation

I have defined function *A* as `A: D*E --> F` and function *B* as `B: S*T --> R`.

Now, I want to define function *C* which gets an instance of *A* functions and an instance of *B* functions as inputs and returns a real number.

What is the correct notation for this function?

Is the following notation correct?

`C: A(.)*B(.) --> R`

Comment: To see how to write your formulas so they look like mathematics rather than like some kind of programming language, you can start here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a mathematics site, let's use mathematical notation.

There is no widely accepted mathematical notation that looks like this: 
`A: D*E --> F`.
However, there is a notation that looks like
$A: D \times E \to F,$
which says that $A$ is a function to which we give an element of the set $D$ and an element of the set $E,$ upon which $A$ produces an element of the set $F.$

Note that in this notation, $D,$ $E,$ and $F$ are sets that may contain many different elements, but $A$ is the name of a particular function.
If you want to describe a function that takes other functions as input, it does not usually make sense to use the name $A$ as part of the "type" of the new function,
any more than it makes sense to use the name of the number $3$ as part of the "type" of a function. What I mean is, you would not write
$f: 3 \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R.$
Technically, you *could* write $f: \{3\} \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R,$
but that's rather silly; it says the first argument to the function must always be $3,$ which kind of defeats the purpose of giving the argument to the function in the first place.

You certainly *can* have a function that acts on functions. Here is an example:
$$ C: (\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R) \times 
(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R) \to \mathbb R.$$
This says that $C$ is a function that takes two arguments, each of which itself is a functions that takes two real numbers arguments, and $C$ returns a real number as its result.
As a more specific example, we could say that $C$ is the function such that
$$ C(f,g) = f(0,0) + g(1,1) $$
for any two functions $f: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$
and $g: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R.$